# Error sending mail in PHPMailer possible error in time zone

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I am trying to send emails with PHPMailer but I have errors

I think the error is because PHPMailer has a different timezone set than php.

Does anyone know how to change the time zone of PHPMailer or what could be the error.

I already did the time zone change but PHPMailer does not recognize it.

```
<?php
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';

date_default_timezone_set('America/Guayaquil');
echo "time zone ".date_default_timezone_get()."<br><br><br>";
echo " date/time ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."<br><br><br>";

// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 4;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host       = 'mitelemercado.com';                    
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->Username   = 'ventas@mitelemercado.com';
    $mail->Password   = 'password SMTPPPP';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
    $mail->Port       = 587;

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('ventas@mitelemercado.com', 'Ventas');
    $mail->addAddress('eduardo.manosalvas2@gmail.com', 'Eduardo Manosalvas');
    $mail->addAddress('quilojose@hotmail.com');
    $mail->addReplyTo('ventas@mitelemercado.com', 'Ventas');

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
?>
```

Errors

```
time zone America/Guayaquil


date/time 2020-09-14 20:55:14


2020-09-15 01:55:14 Connection: opening to mitelemercado.com:587, timeout=300, options=array()
2020-09-15 01:55:14 Connection: opened
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SMTP INBOUND: "220-server1.mitelemercado.com ESMTP Exim 4.93 #2 Mon, 14 Sep 2020 20:55:14 -0500"
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SMTP INBOUND: "220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited,"
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SMTP INBOUND: "220 and/or bulk e-mail."
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-server1.mitelemercado.com ESMTP Exim 4.93 #2 Mon, 14 Sep 2020 20:55:14 -0500 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO mitelemercado.com
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SMTP INBOUND: "250-server1.mitelemercado.com Hello mitelemercado.com [116.192.176.64]"
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SMTP INBOUND: "250-SIZE 52428800"
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SMTP INBOUND: "250-8BITMIME"
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SMTP INBOUND: "250-PIPELINING"
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SMTP INBOUND: "250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN"
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SMTP INBOUND: "250-STARTTLS"
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SMTP INBOUND: "250 HELP"
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-server1.mitelemercado.com Hello mitelemercado.com [116.192.176.64]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-STARTTLS250 HELP
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SMTP INBOUND: "220 TLS go ahead"
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO mitelemercado.com
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SMTP INBOUND: "250-server1.mitelemercado.com Hello mitelemercado.com [116.192.176.64]"
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SMTP INBOUND: "250-SIZE 52428800"
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SMTP INBOUND: "250-8BITMIME"
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SMTP INBOUND: "250-PIPELINING"
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SMTP INBOUND: "250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN"
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SMTP INBOUND: "250 HELP"
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-server1.mitelemercado.com Hello mitelemercado.com [116.192.176.64]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250 HELP
2020-09-15 01:55:14 Auth method requested: UNSPECIFIED
2020-09-15 01:55:14 Auth methods available on the server: PLAIN,LOGIN
2020-09-15 01:55:14 Requested auth method not available:
2020-09-15 01:55:14 Auth method selected: LOGIN
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SMTP INBOUND: "334 VXNlcm5hbWU6"
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: dmVudGFzQG1pdGVsZW1lcmNhZG8uY29t
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SMTP INBOUND: "334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6"
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: RW1wcmVzYXJpbzEwLg==
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SMTP INBOUND: "235 Authentication succeeded"
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 Authentication succeeded
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<ventas@mitelemercado.com>
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SMTP INBOUND: "250 OK"
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<eduardo.manosalvas2@gmail.com>
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SMTP INBOUND: "250 Accepted"
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Accepted
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<quilojose@hotmail.com>
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SMTP INBOUND: "250 Accepted"
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Accepted
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SMTP INBOUND: "354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself"
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Mon, 14 Sep 2020 20:55:14 -0500
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: Eduardo Manosalvas <eduardo.manosalvas2@gmail.com>, quilojose@hotmail.com
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: Ventas <ventas@mitelemercado.com>
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: Reply-To: Ventas <ventas@mitelemercado.com>
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: Here is the subject
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <8juyOgeAajDYwn1DCTqIFktG0J2n0uibWpVlLu0@mitelemercado.com>
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.1.7 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: boundary="b1_8juyOgeAajDYwn1DCTqIFktG0J2n0uibWpVlLu0"
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_8juyOgeAajDYwn1DCTqIFktG0J2n0uibWpVlLu0
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_8juyOgeAajDYwn1DCTqIFktG0J2n0uibWpVlLu0
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_8juyOgeAajDYwn1DCTqIFktG0J2n0uibWpVlLu0--
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: .
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SMTP INBOUND: "250 OK id=1kI0Be-0001WM-C7"
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK id=1kI0Be-0001WM-C7
2020-09-15 01:55:14 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SMTP INBOUND: "221 server1.mitelemercado.com closing connection"
2020-09-15 01:55:14 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 server1.mitelemercado.com closing connection
2020-09-15 01:55:14 Connection: closed
Message has been sent
```

Time zone

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don’t see anything unexpected here. All you’re seeing is that PHPMailer uses UTC timestamps in its debug output (the only sane way to present such things), which the receiving server never sees. PHPMailer sets the date within the message correctly, which you can see in the date header. Also nowhere in the rejection message does it make any mention of there being a problem with timestamps. You’re jumping to the wrong conclusion here.